# jQuery change text based on drop down list option

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Hi I am looking for guidance on how I can change the interest rate value based on what type of account a customer chooses from the drop down.

Form:

```
<form id="account" action="" method="post">
<select id = "acc_type">
<option value="current">Current</option>
<option value="savings">Savings</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="interest" value="">

</form>

<script>
$("#account").change(function() {
    var rate = "0.6%";
    if $(#acc_type).val == ("current") {
        rate = "0.6%");
    } else if $(#acc_type).val == ("savings") {
        rate = "0.8%");
    }
    $(#interest).val = rate;
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rmjKV/
Can I have some explanation of why this does not work?

Comment: There is a sea of errors in your code. http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$("#acc_type").change(function() {
    var rate = "0.6%";
    if ($('#acc_type').val() == "current") {rate = "0.6%";}
    else if ($('#acc_type').val() == "savings") {rate = "0.8%";}
    $('#interest').val(rate);
});
```

Find here http://jsfiddle.net/rmjKV/8/ your jsFiddle working, your old code was full of typos

Comment: @SMKS_ARTS you should be binding to acc_type not account.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work since that is not valid JavaScript. Use a tool like [JSLInt](http://www.jslint.com/) to check your code to see the errors.

You are missing many `(` and `)` in that code.

Look at the [if statements on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

```
if (cipher_char == from_char) {
   result = result + to_char;
   x++;
} else {
   result = result + clear_char;
}
```

Do you see what you are missing? The ( and ) around the check.

Now jQuery val is a method, you are not calling a method. You need (). You can not set .val either.

The [docs for jQuery val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Your selector is also wrong, you are missing quotes.

Learn to use your console! It will show you the errors.

Comment: Yes and also add `"use strict";`

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of syntax errors and improper way of using jQuery functions and selectors

```
$("#account").change(function() {
    var rate = "0.6%";
    if($('#acc_type').val() == "current") 
    {
        rate = "0.6%";
    }
    else if ($('#acc_type').val() == "savings") 
    {
        rate = "0.8%";
    }
    $('#interest').val(rate);
});
```

You need to read more about JS syntax and jQuery selectors and functions use

Check the fiddle update 
http://jsfiddle.net/sedz/rmjKV/2/

Answer (score 0):

JSHint doesn't validate your code. Aside that, it looks like you are binding to the `form` change not the `acc_type` change.

```
$("#acc_type").change(function() {

}
```

**Valid JS Code:**

```
$("#acc_type").change(function()
{
   var rate = "0.6%";
   if ($("#acc_type").val() == "current")
   {
      rate = "0.6%";
   } else if ($("#acc_type").val() == "savings")
   {
      rate = "0.8%";
   }

   $("#interest").val(rate);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rmjKV/5/

Answer (score 0):

Stuff like this

```
$(#acc_type)
```

should be

```
$('#acc_type')
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got numerous errors in your code. I think I've fixed most of them below.

I've also wrapped you code in jquery's [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function, so the the script doesn't try and add the event before the page is fully loaded etc.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#account').change(function() {
        var rate = "0.6%";
        if ($('#acc_type').val() == "current") {
            rate = "0.6%";
        } else if ($('#acc_type').val() == "savings") {
            rate = "0.8%";
        }
        $('#interest').val(rate);
    })
})
```